# Can you die / lose all your health at the very end of Bastion?

Tags: bastion

In the final level of Bastion, you reach a point where

> you must choose whether to take Zulf and save him or leave him and fight the Ura yourself.

Is it possible to die after this point?  Even though you still can take hits, your health bar actually goes away as does your potion count, so it's unclear whether you are still taking damage or if that entire scene is just an interactive cinematic.

> In the Take Zulf branch, you actually are prompted to heal at times.  What happens if you don't or are out of potions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No, you cannot die.**

> I played through twice, and when I took Zulf the second time, it became evident pretty quickly that I was taking more damage than I should be able to when slowly trodding toward the exit. I didn't heal up but remained alive until the point where they stopped attacking me.

It appears to be a scripted event for cinematic purposes.